# Delete Cascade with Script

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I have 3 tables,which are not created with the **ON DELETE CASCADE** option, nor is it an option to create them as such.

I may need to delete from all three tables in succession.  Is there a way to do this using only the promotion_id as a key?  Because I need to delete in reverse order, the promotion_id is gone by the time I get to the dependent tables.

I am thinking that the only way to do this is to **SELECT** the keys of the 3 tables using a **JOIN**, and then use them individually.  But it would be nice if there was a pure SQL solution to it.

I am using JDBC, Spring, and Oracle.  Thanks.

create table test_rates (
      rate_id varchar2(10) primary key,
      rate number
    );

```
create table test_offers (
  offer_id varchar2(10) primary key ,
  rate_id varchar2(10),
  foreign key (rate_id) references test_rates (rate_id)
);

create table test_promotions (
  promotion_id varchar2(10) primary key ,
  offer_id varchar2(10),
  foreign key (offer_id) references test_offers (offer_id)
);

insert into test_rates (rate_id,rate) values (1,199);
insert into test_offers (offer_id,rate_id) values (11,1);
insert into test_promotions (promotion_id,offer_id) values (21,11);

commit;

delete from test_promotions where promotion_id = 21;

delete from test_offers where offer_id in (select offer_id from test_promotions where promotion_id = 1);  -- key is gone by now
```

Answer (score 0):

In the common case, when there are N promotions (N>1) for a single offer, it wouldn't make sense to delete the offer if **one** promotion only is deleted. You would end up with orphaned promotions.

If you want to delete a rate, it would make sense to start with deleting all children `promotions` then all children `offers` then delete the `rate`. In that case though, the `rate_id` could be used along the way.

If you delete a child record, there's no need to delete the parent record unless of course this is a requirement, in which case start with looking for the parent id and see above.